# Change background color of figure when using worldmap

Tags: matlab, mapping

When using worldmap.m from the MATLAB Mapping toolbox, the default color of the background (aka the ocean) is 'none'.  How can I change this to a different color?

```
h = worldmap('World')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the `findobj` and `set` functions, you can location the background patch and then use `set` to change the color.

```
h = worldmap('World')
p = findobj(h,'type','patch'); % Find background
set(p,'FaceColor',[1 1 1]); % Change background to white
```